# DFP: Getting the current click-through URL

Tags: google-dfp

I am setting up a DFP for multiple site, we have a set of line items and for each of it's creatives, the current click through is going to `example.com` (our own `.com` site), but since we are running multiple TLDs, we also want the click through URL to change accordingly. For example, when the ads is being displayed in the `.jp`, the click through should go to `.jp`.

In the DFP API reference, there's a function to change the click-through URL: http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650154&expand=adslot_details#setClickUrl

But in order to change our click-through URL, we also need to know what's the current URL. Example case: we need to get `http://www.example.com/products/1` from the DFP `adSlot` in order to change it to `http://www.example.jp/products/1`.

I ran through trial and error using chrome web JS console and found a `getClickUrl()` function in the `adSlot` class, but it keeps returning empty string, for example:

```
googletag.defineSlot("/1234/Test_300x250", [300, 250], 'div-1').getClickUrl();
googletag.defineSlot("/1234/Test_300x250", [300, 250], 'div-1').addService(googletag.pubads()).getClickUrl();
```

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the creative, I think it would be a lot easier to do by passing custom variables. You use the **setTargeting** method to pass a custom variable. So your client-side code to display the ad would look like this:

```
googletag.defineSlot("/1234/Test_300x250", [300, 250], 'div-1').setTargeting('region','jp');
```

And then in your HTML creative you use a pattern macro to replace part of the click-through URL.

```
<a href="http://www.example.%%PATTERN:region%%">
<img src="http://www.example.%%PATTERN:region%%/image.jpeg">
</a>
```

And DFP will replace the macro with whatever value you pass via **setTargeting**.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a super simple way to do this - but it is possible.

Basically you can override an internal function in DFP and capture the content of the ad (and the URL) by getting into the DOM of the iframe.

Here is an example which should alert the URL of the ad (I've only tested this in chrome, so it may need tweaking to work in multiple browsers)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DFP test</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
            var gads = document.createElement('script');
            gads.async = true;
            gads.type = 'text/javascript';
            var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
            gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            var slot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/12345678/Test_300x250', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

            slot1.oldRenderEnded = slot1.renderEnded;
            slot1.renderEnded = function(){
                alert(document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href.replace(/^.*&adurl=/,''));
                slot1.oldRenderEnded();
            };

            googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
            googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0' style='width:266px; height:115px;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0');
            });
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are using jQuery its a bit nicer to use something like:

```
$(adUnit).find('iframe:first').contents().find('a')
```

Any questions let me know.

Comment: Thanks. What you're saying is basically replacing the URL after it being rendered. This won't work because it will jump to a DFP page saying that it is an unauthorized redirect, strangely it will work fine if I redirect it to http://www.google.com, not any other domain.

Comment: No, all the above code is useful for is getting the url that the ad would send the user to once clicked... to change it you would then need to replace the TLD and set the new URL using setClickUrl... I just tried to do that though and its not working... setClickUrl does set a URL on the adunit object... but it doesn't seem to be used for the click through like the documentation says... so that is a different issue.

Comment: @MattCooper I just logged in to say thank you very much!! 11 years later! it worked perfectly for display ad unit. Im figuring out how to get info from interstitial/vignette ads since they are triggered only when user clicks in some link #lifesaver